# how do I add a try catch block inside a for loop to catch an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception?

Tags: java, try-catch

I am new to using try catch blocks and I need some direction. I have a program that counts letters entered in a phrase from user input. The letters 'A' through 'Z' are converted to a number between 0 & 25 by subtracting the corresponding value of the Unicode character set index value of the letter that's being processed from the value of 'Z', which is 90. How would I add a try catch block inside the first for loop that translates the character to the index so that if the phrase contains any characters that are not a letter it would catch it in the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I then would have a message that prints out the non letter character in a statement to the user. I know what I want to do but, I'm having a little trouble understanding the syntax that I would need to do this. I tried to add if(counts[i] <= 64 || >= 91), but that doesn't seem to work. Do I need to convert it to a string? I know my code needs to be something like:

```
  try {
     code...
 }
 catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception)
 {
    System.out.println("Not a letter: " + counts);
 }

Here is my code without the try/catch block:

import java.util.Scanner;
public class CountLetters
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] counts = new int[26];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //get word from user
        System.out.print("\n Enter a single word (letters only): ");
        String word = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();
 
        //convert to all upper case
        word = word.toUpperCase();
  
        //count frequency of each letter in string
        for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i++)
          counts[word.charAt(i)-'A']++;
 
        //print frequencies
        System.out.println();
        for (int i=0; i < counts.length; i++)
           if (counts [i] != 0)
               System.out.println((char)(i +'A') + ": " + counts[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException as the name indicates the array is being accessed with index out of the bounds of array, should not be caught in try catchblock, it indicates an issue with your code rather.

Comment: Just check that the character is really a capital letter. You could also do lower-case letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to put `counts[word.charAt(i) - 'A']++` inside a `try-catch` block as shown below:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] counts = new int[26];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Get word from user
        System.out.print("Enter a single word (letters only): ");
        String word = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();// Do not close it.

        // Convert to all upper case
        word = word.toUpperCase();

        // Count frequency of each letter in string
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char ch = word.charAt(i);
            try {
                counts[ch - 'A']++;// Check this for exception
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("'" + ch + "' is non-alphabetic character.");
            }
        }

        // Print frequencies
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
            if (counts[i] != 0) {
                System.out.println((char) (i + 'A') + ": " + counts[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a single word (letters only): hello2world
'2' is non-alphabetic character.

D: 1
E: 1
H: 1
L: 3
O: 2
R: 1
W: 1
```

Some recommendations:

1. Do not close `Scanner(System.in)` as it also closes `System.in` and there is no way to open it again.
2. Do use `{}` for a block for loop or `if/else/else if` even if it just has a single statement.

Comment: so its char ch = word.charAt(i); that i have to check for? I thought I needed to look for something that's less than index 65 which wound be the character 'A' & greater than the the index of 90 which would be 'Z'. word = word.toUpperCase(); converts everything to uppercase so i don't have a problem there. I was trying to look at the variable count. do I need the throw exception at the top? I thought that's was just another way of catching exceptions which i am not doing here. i still have much to learn.

Comment: @StanOverby - As mentioned in the answer, it's `counts[word.charAt(i) - 'A']` that need to be checked for exception. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Sure, no problem. yes, that did work. I just want to better understand this. First, word is the variable that the phrase that the user enters in gets assigned to. Then everything gets converted to uppercase. All of this I understand. The code "char ch = word.charAt(i);"  is the current character being checked so whatever the current character is in the phrase, it subtracts 'A' , which is the index 65, & then ++ adds one to that? I guess what I'm having trouble with is if the character is the symbol $ which is index 36 what happens then? I'm almost there except for that.

Comment: @StanOverby - `I guess what I'm having trouble with is if the character is the symbol $ which is index 36 what happens then?` - In this case, the code will try to get an element from the array, `counts` at the index position, 36 - 65 = -29 i.e. `counts[-29]` which is not valid as the indices in counts range from 0 to 25. I hope, it helps. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification. it looks like I was reading that correctly then. one last question, does the ++ after that increment counts by one or something else? If that's the case what is the reason for the increment?

Comment: @StanOverby - You have understood it correctly. The operator, `++` is a unary operator which increments the value by one.  The reason for the increment: assume `word.charAt(i)` is `A`, then `counts['A' - 'A']` i e `counts[0]` should be incremented by `1` to reflect that the count of `A` has become `1`. The next time `A` is encountered, `counts[0]` should become `2`. I hope, you already know that each position in an `int []` has a default value of `0` and also that `counts[0]` is supposed to store the count of `A`, `counts[1]` is supposed to store the count of `B` and so on.

Comment: Downvoter - It will be helpful if you can leave a comment.

Comment: @LiveandLetLive yep those hits and run sucks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of catching the exception, just check in your loop:

```
        for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char currentChar = word.charAt(i);
            if (currentChar >= 'A' && currentChar <= 'Z') {
                counts[currentChar -'A']++;
            }
        }
```

As was mentioned in the comments, your code shouldn't rely on catching out of bounds exceptions.